# D-Link DWA-131 Adapter Low signal Strength.Same adapter gives full signal strength in Windows

Tags: networking, drivers

I have purchases a small D-link DWA 131(Hardware Version-E1) Wifi-Adapter and i have installed the necessary drivers for the same.But the Adapter gives me a low signal strength when the wifi router is in the next room and when i use this adapter in windows,it gives me a good full signal strength.Any ideas how can i fix this?

I am using Ubuntu 17.10

Edit-output from lsusb-

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:036e Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) Webcam

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2001:3319 D-Link Corp. 

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this question by installing another set of drivers and blacklisting the previous adapter driver that i had installed.This was the source of the conflict and now things are fine again.